# Install xcode 4.3.2 on Mac OS X 10.8.1

Tags: xcode, macos

How can I install two version of Xcode on Mountain Lion?

I want to install xcode 4.3.2 and also keep xcode 4.5 But whenever I try to install 4.3.2 it says it requires Mac OS X 10.7 to install. Any ideas?

Also if i install xcode 4.3.2 I can now compile application with iOS5.1 as base SDK right?

Comment: So your actual goal is to compile apps for iOS 5.1 on Mountain Lion?

Comment: If you are thinking to upload apps on iOS5.1, it would be rejected. And, why to install xcode? Just download the iOS5.1 sdk and it should be fine, no?

Comment: Not sure about 4.3.2, but you can simply rename your old `/Applications/XCode.app`.

If have XCode 4.4 installed as `/Applications/XCode44.app` and 4.5 as `/Applications/XCode.app`; I renamed mine in a terminal prior to installing 4.5.

You can even have both in your dock, simply open your Applications folder, then drag it.

Comment: @Dreyfus15 Why don't you install Xcode 4.4 instead of 4.3.2? Xcode 4.4 has the iOS 5.1 SDK and is supported on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link [SOLVED: How to install XCode 3.2.6 on Lion?](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1289543). I've got old versions of xcode being installed on mac with mountain lion (3.x, 4.x). All you need - correct path to mpkg file from dmg volume with xcode.